# Как реализовать предзагрузку изображений в игре android?

Tags: java, android

У меня такая проблема: есть два фрагмента. Первый загружается при запуске приложения. Второй запускается(замещает первый) при нажатии на кнопку. На втором фрагменте имеется фон: `android:background="@drawable/sputnik"`. На фоне векторное изображение. Так вот проблема в том, что при первом открытии этого фрагмента он открывается долго(где-то 500 мс), но при последующих открытиях мгновенно. Объясните: как загрузить фон фрагмента заранее?

Comment: а у вас есть действие, которое предшествует нажатию на кнопку? Или как вы определите, что пора загружать изображения, ведь пользователь скоро нажмет кнопку? Или вы хотите изображение всегда держать в оперативке?

Comment: Пользователь может сразу нажать на кнопку без предшествующих действий. Да, мне надо всегда держать его оперативке. А можно ведь загрузить картинку в кэш при запуске игры, а потом уже программно установить фон?

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?(